# Best way to Insert a lot rows in database from HTML table using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to insert data of HTML table rows in database,
My table have about 200 rows and each rows have 20 values that must insert to database per table rows.
So i have two solution:

A. i can send each rows data (20 values) to ajax and this job repeat foreach table row.

B. i can implode all data together for examples `name` rows together and `description` rows together and send 20 BIG value with ajax that each of this value have 200 values.

In Solution `A` i afraid that during insert data, internet connection get into problem or any other issue occurred and some rows inserted and some of that not insert, so how must i do?

In solution `B` i afraid about my data get large and when i try send them with `POST` method to my `php` file using ajax, some data lost and can't sent because of data size

How you think? what i must do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to configure your php so it can handle large post data instead of sending so many requests as this is not optimal and may causes some issues to the server, in case you are worried for data loss or something just start sql transaction just when you start inserting and commit it when everything is good, otherwise just roll back and display error message.

Comment: So, if i change php post capacity in my php.ini, i can send big data with on erequest.yeah?

Comment: yes, this is what expected. please tell if it did not work